# How to selectively disable Angular service worker for specific URLs?

Tags: javascript, angular, redirect, service-worker

I have the following Angular Service Worker config file:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "dataGroups": [
       // some data API specific caching strategies follow
  ],
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/index.html",
            "/*.css",
            "/*.js",
            "/*.map"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In general it works fine.

However, during login phase we have a few redirects - the server returns 302 with Location header that contains some authentication codes. The problem is that browser seems to swallow the response silently and turns it into 200. I see Chrome Network tools showing `Status Code: 200  (from ServiceWorker)` instead of `Status Code: 302`. This totally breaks authentication flow and users get stuck in refresh loop.

Unfortunately I don't have total control over the URL that gets requested and I cannot intercept the response - it is all performed by a third-party library.

I would like to somehow tell Angular and the browser to treat some specific http requests as non-serviceable by the service worker, essentially to make them work as good old plain http requests - as if service worker was not installed at all or as if the request was issued to another domain.

**Is there any setting to completely disable service worker for specific URLs? What would be correct way to do that?**

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue?